# Remove a certain character from a string in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a calculation with time and need to remove the ":" which splits hours and minutes.

My array currently holds a string value of "12:04"

I created a for loop to iterate through the second array string by length, check for a :, then remove that character and log the new output. However, my logic is not working as intended. If you can, please let me know what I did wrong so I can fix my issue.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < content[2].length; i++) {
        if (content[2].charAt(i) === ":"){
            content[2].slice(i);
            console.log(content[2])
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that ":" will appear only once, then keep it simple

```
content[2] = content[2].replace(":", "");
```

Full code:

```
const result = content.map(str => str.replace(":", ""))
```

Comment: Just curious. If the time has an AM or PM attached, how would I go about removing this? Would I need to do an iteration, or is there a method to check for string similarities? (can't seem to find)

Comment: @Matt if you want to remove everything except numbers, just do `str.replace(/\D+/g, '')`

Comment: `var parts = content[0].match(/\d+/g)`

Answer (score 0):

I think this works well:

```
content.split(':').join('')
```

Here is the output I got from the console:

```
 "12:04".split(':').join('')
'1204' // Output
```